# MS SQL Server connection reset on AWS if column has more than 39kb

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2012

We migrated an app that does some business inteligence, so it does manage a lot of data.
This app works perfectly on our own environment, but when running in AWS we received a lot of "connection reset" problem.

We have identified that one query retrieves data from a table which has a column with a XML content. The column is VARBINARY(MAX) and the content varies a lot in size. If we do not return that column, the problem goes away.
Investigating a little bit more, only when the content of this column is close or higher than 40kb we got connection reset.

We are running SQL Server 2012 Web Edition, and accessing it throuh JDBC. If we do connect through SQL Server Management Studio the problem persists, so it is not a JDBC or our app problem.

This problem is really similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231778/sql-server-jdbc-connection-reset-error-only-on-amazon-ec2), but in our case we managed to identify that it does so only when column contents are close or higher than 40kb.

MS specify a [2GB limit on VARBINARY(max)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), so it is supposed to work.

Are there limits in AWS? In our environment we use SQL Server 2012 Standard; in AWS is Web Edition, but no source states that there limits in columns size.

**UPDATE:** we ran the query on the same machine using SQL Server Management Studio (previously was remote) and the query did return ok, even with much larger results! So the problem is when running in AWS. The machine that does the access is in AWS too, but another box.

**UPDATE 2:** simple simulation query:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),REPLICATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),'A'), 500000))`

Sometimes lower values as 5000 causes the problem, but intermitent. By informing 500000 you always lose connection. Nothing is appended to the SQL Server logs.

Comment: Have you checked SQL Server logfile?

Comment: Logfile didn't include anything. I suspect that the server executes the query and somehow the connection is shutdown, but after SQL Server.

Comment: Sounds like a misconfigured firewall is blocking ICMP.

Comment: Thanks, but was the MTU configuration. We have lowered the value from 1500 to 1486 and now everything is ok! Strange not to have more info on this on AWS docs or other users posting about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tuning the MTU of your windows box: 
ping -f -l [trial MTU number] [other server IP]

This post explains how to use this tip:
[link](https://serverfault.com/questions/125828/what-should-be-the-mtu-size-for-windows-servers-on-the-same-network)

Hope this help!

Comment: Great tip! We solved the problem changing the MTU value in Windows Server from 1500 to 1486 (1458 + 28). Thanks!